# Does CocoaPods support version control?

Tags: svn, version-control, cocoapods

I've always been confused about how CocoaPods works with version control, if at all.

Suppose I have a project with a CocoaPod installed and I commit my project to a version control system. Later, I issue a 'pod update' command to update my pod. Suppose that the updated version has new files, or it removes some files that used to be in the old version.

Will CocoaPods automatically issue the necessary version control commands to make sure that the changes are reflected when I commit my project? Or is it expecting me to do this manually? If it does support version control, which version control systems does it recognize?

I mostly use SVN, and I seem to have problems whenever I get pod updates that include a lot of changes. Updates that merely change existing files are fine, but some updates include lots of new files, or they rename existing folders, which seems to cause a lot of problems. In particular, the SVN status command will often show me files that no longer exist in my local directory, but are still part of the repository and haven't been scheduled for deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods works purely on the filesystem and does not generate any version control commands.